# Get MediaStreamTrack(audio) from Video

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html5-video, html5-audio, mediastream

I want to record audio from video element alongside recording from canvas.
I have

```
var stream = canvas.captureStream(29);
```

Now I am adding audioTrack of video to the stream.

```
var vStream = video.captureStream();
stream.addTrack(vStream.getAudioTracks()[0]);
```

But this slows down the performance with every video added. As captureStream() is very heavy on video and it also requires a flag to be switched on in Chrome. Is there a way of creating only audio MediaStream from video element without using captureStream().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use the Web Audio API's method [`createMediaElementSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaElementSource) which will grab the audio from your mediaElement, and then the [`createMediaStreamDestination`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/createMediaStreamDestination) method, which will create an MediaStreamDestination node, which contains an MediaStream.

You then just have to connect it all, and you've got your MediaStream with your MediaElement's audio.

```js
// wait for the video starts playing
vid.play().then(_=> {
  var ctx = new AudioContext();
  // create an source node from the <video>
  var source = ctx.createMediaElementSource(vid);
  // now a MediaStream destination node
  var stream_dest = ctx.createMediaStreamDestination();
  // connect the source to the MediaStream
  source.connect(stream_dest);
  // grab the real MediaStream
  out.srcObject = stream_dest.stream;
  out.play();
  });
```

```html
The video's audio will be streamed to this audio elements : <br>
<audio id="out" controls></audio><br>
The original video element : <br>
<video id="vid" crossOrigin="anonymous" src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/bch2j17v6ny4ako/movie720p.mp4?dl=0" autoplay></video>
```

Note that you could also connect more sources to this stream, and also that you can combine it with an other video stream with the `new MediaStream([stream1, stream2])` Constructor (It's currently the only way to combine different streams on FF, until [this bug is fixed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1296531), should be soon though).